# Quick Find / Find in Files scope in Visual Studio 11 Beta

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2008 and 2010, the "Quick Find" and "Find in Files" window had different search scopes. I was using the Quick Find window to search the current document and the find in files window to search the entire solution.

In the new beta version, changing the scope in one window impacts the other window too. Is there a way to go back to the previous behaviour?

Thank you

Comment: This is a known bug in the Visual Studio 11 Beta. A most irritating bug, at that. However, I don't know of any workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fix for this (VS11 BETA ONLY Find Settings Seperator)

I found it at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/04/11/improving-find-amp-replace-in-visual-studio-11-beta.aspx

[Shortcut to fix](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-29-92/6746.VS11_5F00_BETA_5F00_ONLY_2D00_FindSettingsSeparator.vsix)